# Is it possible to create a contiguous multidimensional array at runtime in D?

Tags: arrays, d, memory-layout

I would like to create a rectangular multidimensional array at runtime, such that the entire array is stored in a contiguous block of memory. It is not necessary for the array to be resizable after its initial creation. Effectively, I want to create a static array at runtime, but I would accept an approach that satisfies the stated conditions even if the array is technically of a different type.

More formally, I would like to take two `ulong`s `nr` and `nc`, and create an array `arr` at runtime such that `arr[r][c]` is equivalent to `*(arr.ptr + r * nc + c)`, both in terms of what it evaluates to, and the efficiency with which it does so. (`*(arr.ptr + c * nr + r)` would also be acceptable, although I don't imagine D would use column-major order.)

Is there a way to do this in D?

The closest I've gotten is:

```
import std.stdio, core.memory;

void main() {
    ulong nr = 3, nc = 4;
    auto p = cast(int*)GC.malloc(nr * nc * int.sizeof);
    auto p1 = cast(int[3][4])p[0..12];
}
```

But that fails to compile if I change the `cast(int[3][4])` to `cast(int[nr][nc])`.

---

## Comparison of answers

To compare the different answers provided, I ran the following function (with the indexing expression adjusted as needed) over a 10,000,000 x 20 array of doubles.

```
auto busywork(T)(T p) {
    foreach (r; 0..nr) {
        foreach (c; 0..nc) {
            p[r][c] = r + log(1.0 + c);
        }
    }
    double result = 1.0;
    foreach (t; 0..1) {
        foreach (r; 0..nr) {
            foreach (c; 0..nc) {
                result += log(1.0 + pow(p[r][c], 3));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

- baseline is a one-dimensional array manually indexed using `p[r * nc + c]`.
- baseline_dynamic is a two-dimensional dynamic array
- chunks_array is Bearded Beaver's approach
- chunks is Bearded Beaver's approach without the .array
- array2D is Jack Applegame's (2D) approach with the bounds checks removed from opIndex.

### Runtime

The table reports the median runtime in milliseconds over five runs.

|  | dmd -O | gdc -O3 | gdc -Os | ldc -O3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| baseline | 13592 +/- 1758 | 20978 +/- 434 | 15452 +/- 1178 | 20778 +/- 1017 |
| baseline_dynamic | 13481 +/- 339 | 20782 +/- 501 | 13476 +/- 209 | 20632 +/- 156 |
| chunks | 15800 +/- 144 | 21014 +/- 176 | 13676 +/- 118 | 21203 +/- 212 |
| chunksarray | 12903 +/- 649 | **19648 +/- 1080** | 12895 +/- 519 | 19770 +/- 816 |
| array2d | ***12606 +/- 606*** | 19844 +/- 1042 | **12640 +/- 540** | **19724 +/- 953** |

### Memory Use

- chunks and array2d both had zero memory overhead over baseline.
- chunksarray had a 9% overhead for all compilers.
- baseline_dynamic had 18% overhead under dmd and *41%* overhead for gcc and ldc.

Naturally, relative overhead varies based on the array dimensions and type.

### Conclusions

The tremendous difference between `-O3` and `-Os`, and the fact that `array2d` under `dmd -O` performs *better* than the baseline in some runs (despite the fact that examination of the generated assembly (of a shorter program) showed that `opIndex` was not being inlined by dmd) suggests that the number of cache misses is the dominating factor, at least when the array is eating up a decent proportion of the system's RAM. (Setting -boundscheck=off brings the `dmd -O` version of the baseline in line with the array2d performance, so that's apparently why it array2d did *better* sometimes.)

chunksarray has the advantages of being shorter code and using the same syntax as dynamic arrays, and might become preferable in cases where `nc` and/or `T.sizeof` are large enough that the relative memory overhead becomes less significant, but array2d appears to be the best option in the general case.

Comment: Thank you for the comparison table, good job. I wonder why ldc is so much slower, it's considered very fast

Comment: @BeardedBeaver I suspect it's not ldc that performs poorly, but rather `-O3`.  `gcc -O3` performs similarly poorly to `ldc2 -O3`, but `gcc -Os` does quite well.  I couldn't find a flag in the ldc manual to optimize for code size, so that isn't in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static and dynamic arrays in D have different layout in memory.

A dynamic array is a reference type, and a static array is a value type.

So, there is no way to cast a block of memory into a multidimensional dynamic array.

Instead you will have to create your own type with an overloaded indexing operator.

Basic example:

```d
import std.stdio : writeln;

void main() {
    auto arr = Array2D!int(3, 4);
    arr[2, 3] = 23;
    // arr[3, 3] = 33; // range violation
    writeln(arr[2, 3]);
    writeln(arr.data[0..12]);
}

struct Array2D(T) {
    import core.memory : GC;
    import std.exception : enforce;
    import core.exception : RangeError;
    
    size_t nr, nc;
    T* data;
    this(size_t nr, size_t nc) {
        this.nr = nr;
        this.nc = nc;
        auto ds = nr * nc;
        data = cast(T*) GC.malloc(T.sizeof * ds);
        data[0..ds] = 0;
    }
    
    ref T opIndex(size_t r, size_t c) {
        enforce!RangeError(r >= 0 && r < nr);
        enforce!RangeError(c >= 0 && c < nc);
        return data[c * nr + r];
    }
}
```

Basic generic example:

```d
import std.stdio : writeln;

void main() {
    auto arr = makeArrayMD!int(2, 3, 4);
    arr[1, 2, 3] = 123;
    // arr[2, 2, 3] = 223; // range violation
    writeln(arr[1, 2, 3]);
    writeln(arr.data[0..24]);
}

struct ArrayMD(T, size_t dims) {
    import core.memory : GC;
    import std.algorithm : fold;
    import std.exception : enforce;
    import core.exception : RangeError;
    
    size_t[dims] sizes;
    T* data;
    this(Sizes...)(Sizes szs) if(Sizes.length == dims) {
        sizes = [szs];
        auto ds = sizes.fold!"a * b";
        data = cast(T*) GC.malloc(T.sizeof * ds);
        data[0..ds] = 0;
    }
    
    ref T opIndex(Sizes...)(Sizes szs) {
        size_t idx = 0;
        size_t rs = 1;
        static foreach(i, s; szs) {
            enforce!RangeError(s >= 0 && s < sizes[i]);
            static if(i > 0) rs *= sizes[i - 1];
            idx += s * rs;
        }
        return data[idx];
    }
}

auto makeArrayMD(T, DS...)(DS dims) {
    return ArrayMD!(T, DS.length)(dims);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, dmd generates actual `call` instructions for `opIndex`, even with `pragma(inline, true)` (although it does inline it if I turn `-inline` on globally).

Comment: if you want runtime optimizations use gdc or ldc; dmd focuses on fast compile times rather than fast generated code. (its generated code is often good enough, but never heavily optimized)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe At least for the values I tested these answers against, that turned out not to be the case. `dmd -O` and `gdc -Os` performed about the same, and `-O3` was much worse than either for both `gdc` and `ldc2`.

Comment: yeah there's sometimes exceptions. im kinda surprised this one is though, usually ldc+gdc do a better job at this kind of code. oh well, whatever works

Answer (score 2):

I used `chunks` to create a 2D array that is stored in memory in one piece

```cpp
auto p = new int[](nr * nc);
auto p1 = p.chunks(nc).array;

// now you can set and get values as in usual 2D array
p1[i][j] = 42;
```

More info here: https://dlang.org/library/std/range/chunks.html#1

Comment: A great way to create a wrapper!
Instead of `p[i][j]`, there should be `p1[i][j]`

Comment: Also you don't need `array`.


`auto p1 = p.chunks(nc);` is enough.

Comment: It works without an `array` but according to my tests it's noticably slower than with `array`, that's why I added it.

Comment: With `array`, a second array will be created. But it is really faster, then struct wrapper.

Comment: I accepted Jack's answer, since it gives a bit better performance, but +1 for brevity.  It's worth having a short version in my toolbox for the cases where I'm willing to accept either the memory overhead of the `.array` version or the performance hit of the version without `.array`.

Comment: I need to investigate a little more but from what I see it doesn't perform a deep copy of the first array, it's just a thin wrapper. You only create a one extra 1D array, which should be fine in most cases